# Skip Playframework ScalaWS API URL encoding

Tags: scala, playframework, url-encoding

I am trying to do HTTP get request using [ScalaWS](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWS) API.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.ws.WS

class HttpClient {

  def get(url: String, headers: Map[String, String]): Future[String] = {

    WS.url(url)
    .withHeaders(headers.toSeq: _*)
    .get()
    .map(resp => {
      println(resp)
    }
   )
  }
```

This code does encoding on URL value I am sending to it. However I do not want it to encode the URL I am sending to it.

I tried few ways like adding `play.ws.ahc.disableUrlEncoding` in application.conf file but it is not helping.

So is there any way I can skip this encoding?

Comment: I checked Play 2.5 code though `play.ws.ahc.disableUrlEncoding` should work.FYI You should use Guice DI and remove `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` and `play.api.Play.current`. That's not recommended to use anymore since 2.4

Comment: I added `play.ws.ahc.disableUrlEncoding=true` in `application.conf` file but don't know why it is not working.

Comment: Tried passing a `java.net.URL`?

Comment: @Reactormonk How will that help? Because as per my understanding it encodes when `.get()` method is invoked. So what ever you pass to `.url()` it is going to get encoded.

Comment: Random question: Why wouldn't you encode your URL?

Comment: @insan-e URL I am trying get is generated by third party API which I already taking care of query param encoding.

Comment: @YogeshPatil I've had a look at source code and I didn't find `play.ws.ahc.disableUrlEncoding` setting at all. You'll need to bypass it `somehow` and set `useRawUrl`, see [here](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/1.7.x/src/main/java/com/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpClientConfig.java#L946) and see [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/WS.scala#L52). Also, what version of Play/Ws are you using?

Comment: @insan-e I am using Play 2.4 version. I will try this option.

Comment: @insan-e actually module which is actually making this call is using Play 3.7 version and this configuration is not available with that version.